# React Redux Toolkit - Can we Dispatch/Call from one reducer's action to another reducer's action to change state variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Here I have two state slices and I need to dispatch a method of slice1 within slice2.

How can I call a reducer's action of slice 1 from extra reducer's action of callApiSlice

```
const slice1 = createSlice({
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    login: (state) => {
      state.login = { email: 'email@gmail.com', api_keys: false};
    },
    setApiKey: (state) => {
      state.login.api_keys = true;
    },
  },
}

export const callApi = createAsyncThunk(
  "call-api",
  async (payload, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.post( process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + "/save", payload);
      return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
);

const callApiSlice = createSlice({
  name: "callApiSlice",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [callApi.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      // how to call Slice 1 reducer's action setApiKey to change in login state
    }
  }
});

export default callApiSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: No, reducer functions are ***pure*** functions, so there should be absolutely no side-effects. `setApiKey` needs to be dispatched as an action. This is an XY-problem/question. What is the use case you are trying to really solve here? Can you edit the post to include a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: @DrewReese, thanks, i have updated the question for more clarity to the problem. Please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly invoke reducer functions, but if I'm correctly understanding your question it seems you want "setApiKey" reducer function to run upon dispatch of the `callApi.fulfilled` action. Redux state slices/reducer functions (*i.e. the state reducer tree*) are technically passed every action that is dispatched, and can respond to any of them. Add a reducer case in the `slice1` state slice to handle the `callApi.fulfilled` action.

Example:

```
const slice1 = createSlice({
  name: "slice1",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    login: (state) => {
      state.login = { email: 'email@gmail.com', api_keys: false };
    }
    setApiKey: (state) => {
      state.login.api_keys = true;
    }
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [callApi.fulfilled]: (state) => { // <-- respond/react to action
      state.login.api_keys = true;
    },
  },
}
```

```
export const callApi = createAsyncThunk(
  "call-api",
  async (payload, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post( process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + "/save", payload);
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
);
```

```
const callApiSlice = createSlice({
  name: "callApiSlice",
  initialState,
  extraReducers: {
    [callApi.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      ...
    }
  },
});
```